# Getting styled-jsx to work with tailwindcss in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, styled-jsx

I am trying to get styled-jsx to work with tailwindcss in NextJS.

Live sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-blog-ts-tpl-z05b4?file=/src/pages/index.tsx

In the above sample, I'm trying to get `<h1>Hello World</h1>` found on the `index.tsx` page to change colors using tailwindcss.

For example, if I set the styled-jsx to `@apply text-red-400;` , I expect the `h1` to turn red but it does not. I do know styled-jsx is working since applying `color: green;` changes the `h1` to green.

I tried configuring babel with `styled-jsx-plugin-postcss` but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why but it started to work all of a sudden. I didn't even make a change. Looks like `nodejs` or `nextjs` needed to sleep it off...

Answer (score -2):

I think you don't need styled-jsx for anything related to tailwindcss.

You can use the tailwind classNames directly like this and the styles will be applied:

`<h1 className="text-green-400">Hello World</h1>`

https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-blog-ts-tpl-forked-s5k6x?file=/src/pages/index.tsx:601-648

Comment: I use both. For example, I use it to apply to html tags like h1 so I don't need to go to each h1 and set its individual className.

Comment: Alright, that would be more "natural" to do in a CSS file in my opinion. But since your solution works, feel free to use it 

Comment: There are many valid use-cases where you might want to use tailwind's @apply within a style jsx block. One such example would be where you want to apply tailwind's rules to `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements within a component.

Comment: Okay, TIL

But I still think doing that in CSS is more natural

Comment: for one, CSS files are globally scoped. styled-jsx is scoped to the component.

Comment: If you have any dynamic classes, tailwind will not work with those. i.e. you have a theme described via backend DB for link/hover colors, then you have to do that with something like JSX. How tailwind works, you can't do things like 'text-[${myCustomLink}]', etc.